# Playing mp3 on iPhone in background - AudioQueue: Error

Tags: iphone, background, audio, mp3

Hi 
I am developing an app that plays a different buffered mp3 on loop of 5 minutes.
When the app runs in foreground or in iphone standby mode it plays ok, but when I try to 
in background but it give me this error:

Thu Feb 17 00:05:06 unknown mediaserverd[2303] : 00:05:06.158  AudioQueue: Error -12985 from AudioSessionSetClientPlayState(3582)
Thu Feb 17 00:05:06 unknown mediaserverd[2303] : 00:05:06.167  AudioQueue: Error -12985 from AudioSessionSetClientPlayState(3582)

More information: when I play the buffered mp3 (first off corse) in cicle, it plays well i background. I also try to save the buffered mp3 data to a mp3 file and then play but it's the same problem.
I searched for this error but I didn't find relevant information.

Thanks in advance.

There (I think) the relevant code:

```
-(void) prepareAudio {
    // Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

    // The AmbientSound category allows application audio to mix with Media Player
    // audio. The category also indicates that application audio should stop playing 
    // if the Ring/Siilent switch is set to "silent" or the screen locks.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];

    // Use this code instead to allow the app sound to continue to play when the screen is locked.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

    UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                             sizeof (doSetProperty),
                             &doSetProperty
                             );

    /*UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
    OSStatus result = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
    */
    // Activates the audio session.

    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
}


- (void)finishedReceivingData:(NSData *)data {  
    if(data == nil) {
        NSLog(@"cdata nil");
        return;
    }
    if (player != nil) {
        [player release];
        player = nil;
    }

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error: nil];
    [player setVolume:0.1];     
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: Say, did you have any luck figuring this out?  I have the same problem.

Comment: i get the same error on occasion, when there's a lot of sequential calls to play sounds; the app is foregrounded when this happens. any insights on this?